# How to put a passing parameter into <p:confirm message="">?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

This is what I've got:

```
   <p:growl id="message" showDetail="true" />

 <p:commandButton value="delete user" actionListener="#{bean.deleteUser(user)}"  update="@form"> 
 <p:confirm header="Confirm" message="Are you sure to delete #{user.username}?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
   </p:commandButton>

   <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
      <p:commandButton value="yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"  />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
       </p:confirmDialog>
```

The variable `#{user.username}` won't be shown at all. 
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think `<p:confirm` works local in the browser. EL expressions are possible in the message text, but they will be evaluated at rendering time not execution time.

Comment: Your code seems correct to me. I think variable `#{user.username}` might be not initialized. Can you show managed beans listing?

Comment: @Artem I'm afraid I cannot show it. But what I can say is that when I do "bean.deleteUser(user)" , it passes correctly the parameter user, so that it'll delete it. 
So user is initialized and contains the effective user to delete.

Comment: @Marco Try to put your message inside `p:confirmDialog` like  this: `<p:confirmDialog...><p:outputLabel value="Are you sure to delete #{user.username}?"/>...`

Comment: @Artem Tried it and it gives me a wrong username. This is so weird...

Comment: @Artem if I put something like {5}, into the message parameter, it gives me exactly that number.. so it works this way, but not with passing parameter

Comment: @Marco i have this `<p:confirm message="#{msg['button.delete']} #{folderView.folderContentModel.select.name}?"...` code in my project and it works (tested with Primefaces 5.2 and 5.3). So maybe field `username` not initialized

Comment: Read the comment by @Holger carefully. I think he is right. So unless you 'update' the p:confirm, it won't show what you selected but the initial value